# want to download images from server

Tags: php, ftp, file-transfer

I want to transfer site from shared hosting server to dedicated server.current server has folder,which includes approx. 16000 images...we can not use FTP to download these much images.and i do not have SSH rights? how can i download images from this shared hosting server.

Comment: @sonal if you dont have ssh or ftp what do you have? HTTP?

Comment: i have FTP.but because there are approx. 16000 images,server got disconnected after very few time.

Comment: The current server is on shared hosting? I ask because you said "how can i download images from dedicated server" while you say that you want to move from shared to dedicated servers. If the images are in your http-server's htdocs, you could use wget to download them to the dedicated server.

Comment: sorry.current server is shared.i want to transfer to dedicated server.

Comment: can you please provide me script?

Comment: Link The FTP between both servers and use it

Comment: i have tried using this also exec("wget -r -l 0 siteurl");  but server has exec function disabled for security reasons

Answer (score 1):

> we can not use FTP to download these much images

Nonsense. FTP (the protocol) is perfectly capable of downloading 16000 files. If your FTP program is causing you trouble, simply pick a better FTP program. If you can handle commandline applications, `wget` is nice, since it supports recursion and continuation.

Comment: Also might be a setting in the FTP program that miss-matches the site

Answer (score 0):

Unless they are located within a directory that is within the web root of a web application server you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Zip them all, adapted from http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php

```
    <?php

        function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = false) {
          //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
          if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
          //vars
          $valid_files = array();
          //if files were passed in...
          if(is_array($files)) {
            //cycle through each file
            foreach($files as $file) {
              //make sure the file exists
              if(file_exists($file)) {
                $valid_files[] = $file;
              }
            }
          }
          //if we have good files...
          if(count($valid_files)) {
            //create the archive
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
              return false;
            }
            //add the files
            foreach($valid_files as $file) {
              $zip->addFile($file,$file);
            }
            //debug
            //echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

            //close the zip -- done!
            $zip->close();

            //check to make sure the file exists
            return file_exists($destination);
          }
          else
          {
            return false;
          }
        }


    //glob images folder into an array
    foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
        $files_to_zip[]='images/'.$filename;
    }
    //create the zip
    $result = create_zip($files_to_zip,'my-images.zip');
    if($result==true){echo'<a href="my-images.zip">Download Images</a>';
}else{
echo'Could not create zip';}

    ?>
```